# Run docker container Error: Could not find base path /models/model for servable model

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Im have problem when I've trying to run a docker container using docker image: tensorflow/serving.

1. I run the cmd:

`docker run --name=tf_serving -it tensorflow/serving`

2. The result is:

```
2019-10-28 04:23:56.858540: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:462] Adding/updating models.
2019-10-28 04:23:56.858571: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:573]  (Re-)adding model: model
2019-10-28 04:23:56.858852: E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:362] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: Could not find base path /models/model for servable model
```

I've digging to resolve it but still there. Could anyone please have any idea for this, thanks so much!

Comment: This may help https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker

Comment: giving a link to entire docker documentation is a really sloppy way to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, for someone who has the same problems, we need to provide the model path in the local computer and in docker:

```
docker run --name=the_name -p 9000:9000 -it -v "/path_to_the_model_in_computer:/path_to_model_in_docker" tensorflow/serving:1.15.0 --model_name=MODEL_NAME --port=9000
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --name tensorflowserving \
--mount type=bind,source=absolute path to model/resnet,target=/models/resnet \
-e MODEL_NAME=resnet -t tensorflow/serving
```

The **models** was the course of this error in my case.

**explaination of arguements which i found very helpful**

- -p 8501:8501: This is the REST Endpoint port. Every prediction request will be made to this port. For instance, you can make a
  prediction request to http://localhost:8501.

  — name tensorflowserving: This is a name given to the Docker
  container running TF Serving. It can be used to start and stop the
  container instance later.

  — mount type=bind,source=/Users/tf-server/img_classifier/,

  target=/models/img_classifier: The mount command simply copies the
  model from the specified path (/Users/tf-server/img_classifier/) into
  the Docker container (/models/img_classifier), so that TF Serving has
  access to it

Answer (score -1):

You should provide the saved model path. Serving container will find all the models in its `/models` dir. You can use `-v` for `docker run` command. Doing like this:

```sh
docker run --name=tf_serving -it -v /path/to/saved_model:/models/saved_model tensorflow/serving
```